# Drawing p5.js canvas inside a html canvas using drawImage()

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js, processing.js

I am trying to draw the p5.js canvas into a html canvas using drawImage(), but getting an error every time:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

```js
var cnv;
var counterUp = 1;

var canvas2d = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas2d.getContext('2d');

var p5Canvases = document.getElementById('defaultCanvas0');


function setup() {
  pixelDensity(1);
  cnv = createCanvas(1062, 600);
  cnv.parent('p5Container');

}

function draw() {
  background(50,0,0);
  rect(50 + counterUp,50,50,50);

if (truer) {
  if (counterUp < 100) {
    counterUp = counterUp + 1;
  }
}

  context.rect(0,0,canvas2d.width,canvas2d.height);
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.fill();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(100, 200 + counterUp, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.fill();
}

context.drawImage(p5Canvases, 20, 10);
```

Comment: Like it says, the provided value (`p5Canvases`) isn't a canvas. Log it and see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

the p5.js canvas is a special p5.js object. if you console.log(yourp5canvas) you'll notice that it outputs a d.Renderer2D object, and does store the actual HTMLcanvas and HTMLcanvas context within the p5js object.

here's a jsfiddle of how to copy the p5 canvas onto a html canvas. the html canvas has a black border.

->https://jsfiddle.net/ozsLtxhb/261/

the dimensions are a little odd after moving it to the new canvas, but hopefully you can mess around with it and figure it out.

good luck! :)

```
function setup() {
        var HTMLcanvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
    var HTMLcontext = HTMLcanvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvas1 = createCanvas(200, 200);
    console.log(canvas1);
      //gives you "d.Renderer2D" object
    var real_canvas = canvas1.canvas;

    background(200);
    text("p5.js canvas", 10, 10);

        HTMLcontext.drawImage(real_canvas, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: This fixes the "little oddness" `<canvas id="my-canvas" width="400" height="400" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></canvas>` I'm using 2x stuff, that should probably be dynamic based on the user.